# Vuex Axios headers returns Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function from Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm currently using Nuxt and I created a central ApiClient in my app using axios.

**services/apiClient.js**

```js
import axios from "axios";
import store from '../store/index';

const token = () => {
  return store().getters.getToken;
};

const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: "this-is-a-url",
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Api-Key': token() // this returns error: Object(...) is not a function from Vuex
  }
});

axiosClient.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  console.log(token()); // this prints the token type string
  return config;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

When I use the `token()` in axios headers, I'm getting the error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object(...)` but when I call it from axios interceptor I'm getting the correct token type String.

**store/index.js**

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import * as sessions from './modules/sessions';

const store = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    getters: {
      isAuthenticated() {
        return sessions.state.token != null;
      }
    },
    modules: {
      sessions
    }
  });
};

export default store;
```

**store/modules/sessions.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const state = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token') || null,
};

export const mutations = {
  SET_TOKEN(state, token) {
    state.token = token;
  }
};

export const actions = {
  login({ commit }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.get(`/retrieveKey`)
        .then(response => {
          localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.value);
          commit('SET_TOKEN', response.data.value);
          resolve(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  },
  logout({ commit }, context) {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    window.location.reload();
  }
};

export const getters = {
  getToken(state) {
    return state.token;
  }
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you please share the relevant contents of `store/index`? Does it export a function? How are the _getters_ defined?

Comment: @Phil I updated the question, I added the `session module vuex` and the `store/index`

Comment: Why is your store exported as a function?

Answer (score 1):

### Latest answer

May be you can put console.log to debug the value of store(), store().getters and store().getters.getToken inside the token function like below and compare the difference values between axiosClient call and interceptors call.

```
const token = () => {
  const store = store();
  const getters = store.getters;
  const getToken = getter.getToken;
  console.log(store, getters, getToken)
  return getToken;
};
```

Error message of "this returns error: Object(...) is not a function from Vuex" is because of token is equal to **null** in axiosClient.

It is because of 
Initial state of the localStorage.getItem('token') is null/undefined and hence its value becomes **null** before the login done.

```
export const state = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token') || null,
};
```

---

Refer to [Getters of Vuex guide](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access), the getters will be exposed on the `store.getters` object, and you access values as properties.

May be you can get the token value via `store.getters.getToken` instead of `store().getters.getToken`?

Comment: Still not working, as you can see from the axios interceptor I'm using the token function, and I'm getting the actual token. But when I use it inside the headers of axiosClient I'm getting the error